# Why does this batch script create seemingly random directories?

Tags: batch-file

I was playing around and executed the following `.bat`

```
@echo off
mkdir %~dp0
pause
```

This created two directories at the batch location:

- "and"
- "Settings" (inside this: "Usuario", inisde this "Escritorio", inisde this "123")

**Note:** I executed the batch from a "123" directory

I want some background to understand what just happened

Comment: and what does `echo %~dp0` show you?

Comment: @GregHewgill `"C:\Documments and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\123\"` and just for the record, "Escritorio" means Desktop in Spanish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mkdir` command makes all the directories specified on the command line (separated by spaces). For example,

```
mkdir foo bar
```

will make the directories `foo` *and* `bar`. In your case, the argument is `C:\Documents and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\123`, equivalent to:

```
mkdir C:\Documents and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\123
```

Since `mkdir` doesn't know any different, it thinks you want to create the three directories named:

- `C:\Documents`
- `and`
- `Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\123`

You could try doing:

```
mkdir "%~dp0"
```

and see if the double quotes help.

Comment: +1. Beat me by a mouse click on the `submit` button (and your answer is better than mine would have been, too). :)

Comment: Thanks! I really hate to have random stuff stored on my PC (I would have never guessed that it also created `C:\Documents`, now I deleted it)

Comment: Just a last thing, I created the var `set cur="%~dp0"` and I am using like this `mkdir %cur%bananas`, is it a problem to have `'"C:\path\"bananas' instead of '"C:\path\bananas"'`?

Comment: I don't think that's a problem, but I'm not sure. You'd have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you executed it in C:\Documments and Settings..., but have not escaped it, it is splitting the path based on whitespace:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\...
```

gets split into `"C:\Documents"`, `"and"`, `"Settings\..."`

If you escape it with `""` i.e. `"%~dp0"` that should work: it will expand to `"C:\Documments and Settings\..."` which will not be split up